# JLabel goes out of alignment (aka funky) when overlaying a rectangle on it

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a GUI I am making for the popular software `ImageMagick` in Java SWING.
Now, I am implementing the `Crop` feature into it and was trying to implement a drawable box to denote the region to be cropped.
The issue is that although I have gotten the rectangle to draw on the `JLabel`, the `JLabel` itself starts to move around once I finish painting the graphics on it.
As an example, here is a screenshot of the app [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVNA0.jpg) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN10W.jpg) the selection is made.

Here is the code for the `MouseReleased()` event listener

```
private void input_showerMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
    end_x = evt.getX();
    end_y = evt.getY();
    paint(input_shower.getGraphics());
    input_shower.revalidate();
}
```

Here is the code for the `paint()` method

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    Rectangle2D.Double rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(start_x, start_y, (end_x - start_x), (end_y - start_y));
    g2.draw(rectangle);
}
```

Are there any ideas as to why this is happening and any possible solutions?

Comment: This looks extremely sketchy: `paint(input_shower.getGraphics());`. Why are you doing this? You should do passive graphics drawing only in the paintComponent method.

Comment: `paint()` is an overriden method for my `JLabel`

Comment: It's a bad idea what you're doing.

Comment: Please see example in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dangerous code:

```
private void input_showerMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
    end_x = evt.getX();
    end_y = evt.getY();
    paint(input_shower.getGraphics());
    input_shower.revalidate();
}
```

since you're painting directly to a component with a Graphics object that was not given to you by the JVM. Just don't do this, and instead paint passively.

Instead use end_x and end_y in your listened to jcomponent's paintComponent method and draw with that.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PaintComponentCorrect extends JPanel {
   public static final String BULL_FIGHT = "https://duke.kenai.com/misc/Bullfight.jpg";
   private static final Color RECT_COLOR = new Color(150, 150, 255);
   private int startX;
   private int startY;
   private int endX;
   private int endY;
   private BufferedImage img;

   public PaintComponentCorrect() throws IOException {
      URL url = new URL(BULL_FIGHT);
      img = ImageIO.read(url);

      MyMouseAdapt myMouseAdapt = new MyMouseAdapt();
      addMouseListener(myMouseAdapt);
      addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapt);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (img != null) {
         g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
      }
      g.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
      int x = Math.min(startX, endX);
      int y = Math.min(startY, endY);
      int width = Math.abs(startX - endX);
      int height = Math.abs(startY - endY);
      g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet() || img == null) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapt extends MouseAdapter {
      private BufferedImage subImg;

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            return;
         }
         startX = e.getX();
         startY = e.getY();
         endX = startX;
         endY = startY;
         repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            return;
         }
         endX = e.getX();
         endY = e.getY();
         repaint();
         int x = Math.min(startX, endX);
         int y = Math.min(startY, endY);
         int w = Math.abs(startX - endX);
         int h = Math.abs(startY - endY);


         subImg = img.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);
         ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(subImg);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PaintComponentCorrect.this, icon);
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         endX = e.getX();
         endY = e.getY();
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      PaintComponentCorrect mainPanel = null;
      try {
         mainPanel = new PaintComponentCorrect();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("PaintComponent Correct");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: + 1, yes and you should never invoke the paint() method (or any painting method) directly. You invoke repaint() when you want the component to repaint itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
```

1. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method.
2. You then invoke super.paintComponent(), not "paintComponents" with an "s"

For example check out [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The code isn't designed to do what you want, but it does show how to draw a Rectangle on a component using the above suggestion.

Comment: The thing is I am using Netbeans to design my GUI and it doesn't allow me to change the predefined code.  
How can I override the `paintComponent()` method?

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly: another reason not to use NetBeans or other code-generation library. But look into it as it **will** allow you to override paintComponent.

Comment: It looks like the OP is overriding `paint` of a something like `JFrame`, hence the user of `paintComponents` - it's a guess, but I've seen it before +1